# Problems with Facebook fql.query

Tags: sql, facebook-fql

I have some problems with this fql.query method:

```
select music 
  from user 
  where uid = ...... 
    and music in (select music 
                    from user
                    where uid = ......
                 )
```

I want to obtain common music interest between two users; it works with queries like this

```
select uid 
  from user
  where uid = ......
    and uid in (select uid 
                  from user
                  where uid = ......
               )
```

I think the problem is that the second query returns an integer and the first one returns a string array.  Can anyone help me with this?

(*Excuse my bad English! I'm from Spain* ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Does not the first query already gives you your answer?

I mean it does the following :

```
-- Display only music field
select music 
from user 
where uid = <first_USER> -- Selection of your first user 
and music in ( -- We want to macth the string with another
    select music -- Selects only the music field
    from user
    where uid = <second_USER> -- Selection of your second user
)
```

So you gets a music name that match in two user records.

Your second query seems a bit odd to me :

```
select uid
  from user
  where uid = <first_USER?>
    and uid in (select uid 
                  from user
                  where uid = <second_USER?>
               )
```

Which basically translates to find the user_id matching user one and user two. Thing that does never happen since each user has it's own uid.

By the way, I don't know how facebook handles music string, but it may appear that user don't write their favorite music name in a common spelling and/or format. That may impede your matching system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!,the second query it's a absurd yes,i only want to show that the queries like that works,i think it's because uid is an integer and music have a weird format like you said...

Comment: Right. So does it work for you? Or did you need more precisions? (If it's ok, don't forget to accept the answer and vote up please)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
select music 
  from user 
  where uid=UID1
AND music IN (SELECT music from user where uid=UID2)
```

And it works fine when the UID1 `music` string matches exactly the UID2's one.

Comment: ¿Did you try it in the test console? ¿and works? i can't make it works and i don't know why.

Comment: Do you have two users that have exactly the same music string?